# For TCP, does returning from "write()" mean that the peer app has "read()" the data?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I'm writing a C/S program and both the client and server may send data  to peer (without explicit ack) at arbitrary time. I'm wondering if it could possibly deadlock if the client and server coincidentally write to the peer at the same time.

So does returning from `write()` mean that the peer application has already `read()` the data? Or it only means the peer's kernel has got the data and would deliver to the app on next `read()`?

---

(EJP's answer fixed my totally wrong understanding about `write()/send()/...`. To add some authoritative info I found this in the POSIX standard about [`send`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html):

> Successful completion of a call to send() **does not guarantee delivery of the message**. A return value of -1 indicates only locally-detected errors.

Linux's man page about `send()` is not very clear:

> No indication of failure to deliver is implicit in a send().  Locally detected errors are indicated by a return value of -1.

Or it's because I cannot fully understand the first sentence as a non native English speaker. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it could possibly deadlock if the client and server coincidentally write to the peer at the same time.

It can't, unless one or both of the peers is very slow reading and has closed its receive window. TCP is full-duplex.

> So does returning from write() mean that the peer application has already read() the data?

No.

> Or it only means the peer's kernel has got the data and would deliver to the app on next read()?

No.

It means the data has reached *your* kernel, and is queued for transmission.

> the returning from write() means the TCP ACK has already been received.

No it doesn't.

> u mean returning from write() only means the data has reached the sender's kernel?

That is not only what I meant, it is what I said.

> I'd think the sender's already received the TCP ACK so reached the peer's kernel.

No.

Comment: *"the data has reached **your** kernel"* -- u mean returning from write() only means the data has reached the ***sender***'s kernel? i'd think the sender's already received the TCP ACK so reached the peer's kernel.

Comment: @pynexj You are mistaken. There is no guarantee that the data has even been sent, let alone ACK'd. If you think you know the answer why are you asking the question?

Comment: not that i know the answer. my understanding is it's reached the peer's kernel. what i don't know is if the peer's app has called read(). sounds like my whole understanding is wrong.

Comment: @pynexj Returning from `write` means that the sender was able to store the data in transmit butter. If the buffer is full, `write` will be blocked and return a bit later. Otherwise it will return immediately. Your `write` call would also return successfull if the peer burnt to ashes straight after accepting the connection.

Comment: yes thank you all. i found the info from the posix standard. added to my question for easy reference for others.

Comment: a bit out of topic, anyone can help translate *"No indication of failure to deliver is implicit in a send()"* (from send()'s man page on linux) into simple English?

Comment: @pynexj I agree with you. It is a poorly worded and most obscure statement. What they are trying to say is that failure to deliver *this* data won't necessarily be indicated as a return value/`errno` of *this* invocation of `send()`, due to buffering and all the other malarkey. You will eventually get an error, on a subsequent `send()` or `recv()`, relating to this data, but it may take some time. Why they didn't just adapt the Posix text, or the original BSD text, is another mystery.

Answer (score 3):

No. If you think of it as a data pipe, returning from `write` means that your data has *entered* the pipe, *not* that it has exited the pipe at the other end.

In fact, since the pipe is one where the data may take any of hundreds of different pathways, you're not even guaranteed that it *will* reach the other end :-) If that happens, you'll be notified about it at some later date, probably by a *subsequent* `write` failing.

It may be blocked:

- trying to exit your machine due to a broken cable,
- at a bottleneck in the path somewhere,
- by the networking stack at the destination,
- by a networking stack at some device in the networking path, more intelligent than a simple hub,
- because the application at the other end is otherwise tied up,
- and so on.

A successful return from `write` means that your *local* network stack has accepted your data and will process it in due course.

Comment: *"It may be blocked trying to exit your machine due to a broken cable, it may be blocked at a bottleneck in the path somewhere"* -- this is not possible since the returning from `write()` means the TCP ACK has already been received. so it's more like the pipe is between the peer's kernel and app.

Comment: @pynexj It means nothing of the kind. Are you asking or telling?

Comment: as i commented in EJP's answer, my understanding is it's reached the peer's kernel. what i don't know is if the peer's app has called read(). sounds like my whole understanding is wrong.

Comment: sorry i did not realize it's EJP asking here. :)

Comment: To add to what @EJP has already correctly explained, think about what would happen to download rates if every write() call had to wait until peer receipt ACK before returning.  Imagine a high bandwidth, but also high latency, connection, eg. a satellite link...